# Execute script after page loads in javascript/jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, bookmarklet

I am not the original writer of this bookmarklet but am trying to improve/update it to execute the script after the page loads. I would like to hit the bookmarklet as the page loads and it will perform the task when it does finally load. I've tried many forms of $(document).ready and jQuery(document).ready(function($) to no avail. Please assist. Thank you

```
javascript:(function(){ 
function setName(){ 
    jQuery.noConflict(); 
    jQuery("#456_linier").dblclick(); 
    jQuery("#456").val("First Name Last"); 
    jQuery("input[title='Save']").click(); 
} 

if (typeof jQuery == 'undefined') { 
    var s = document.createElement('script'); 
    s.setAttribute('src','https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js'); 
    s.setAttribute('type','text/javascript'); 
    document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(s); 
    } 
    setTimeout(setName, 1000); })();
```

Answer (score 1):

Note: "after the page loads" can mean many things, so I interpreted it as "after all html loaded", figuring that's a fairly robust interpretation.

This should take care of you, with a little vanilla Javascript:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
  console.log("Whatup Homie!!!");
});
```

Comment: I added this before `function setName(){` and unfortunately the code still didn't run until I pressed the bookmarklet again after the page fully loaded.

Comment: Yo - added an addition to this below

Answer (score 0):

Wrapping the function declaration won't do it, and anyway I think setTimeout autofires the function if you don't do it like a callback. try this:
[image]

Or potentially this strategy, with eventListener inside the load function itself:

[image]

Comment: I removed the original document.addEventListener and added what you put at the bottom (and removing the `setTimeout(setName, 1000);` that was at the very bottom) and now nothing happens at all and I'm not getting any errors in the console either which I'm finding odd. How the code was original written in the question works, it just doesn't work until the page is fully loaded. Thanks for the help!